# How to check that location have been visited with Flatlist ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

First of all, sorry about my bad English. I'm having an issue that when I click on one location, it will show the "Checked" text on the corner, but when I click on another location, it will show the "checked" like the first, but the first "Checked" one reset to "not check", so how to keep the first result?

Here is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null) 

  const renderView = ({item}) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelectedId(item.id) }
       style={{
       marginBottom:15,
       marginHorizontal:7,
       width:'46%',
       height:200,
       }}>
         <Image style={{width:'100%',height:'100%', borderRadius:20,}} source={{uri:item.image}}/>
         <Text style={{position:'absolute',bottom:0,padding:15,color:'yellow', fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.title}</Text>
      <View style={{
        position:'absolute',
        right:0,
        padding:15,
        }}>
        {
          item.id === selectedId?<Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'red'}}>Checked</Text>:<Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'red'}}>Not check</Text>   
        }   
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  )
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.top}>
        <View style={{
          height:44,
          width:44,
          backgroundColor:'green',
          alignItems:'center',
          justifyContent:'center',
          borderRadius:30,
        }}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:25,color:'white'}}>=</Text>
        </View>
          <Text style={{fontSize:25,color:'blue',fontWeight:'bold'}}>Packages</Text>
        <View style={{
            height:44,
            width:44,
            backgroundColor:'green',
            alignItems:'center',
            justifyContent:'center',
            borderRadius:30,
        }}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:25,color:'white'}}>@</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={{
          marginVertical:10,
          flex:1,
          paddingHorizontal: 15
        }}>
          <FlatList
            data = {DATA}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={renderView}
            keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
          />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: 'https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/298/610/503/vietnam-ho-chi-minh-city-cityscape-dusk-thumbnail.jpg',
    title: 'Ho Chi Minh city',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: 'https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/582/203/631/ha-noi-city-vietnam-lake-thumbnail.jpg',
    title: 'Ha Noi city',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/sunny-beach-in-the-pearl-island-of-phu-quoc-vietnam-picture-id1307905856?b=1&k=20&m=1307905856&s=170667a&w=0&h=MMd7neh6NOOxeUUlo6eCeU49vWp7HhQXtgTw0VNjogo=',
    title: 'Phu Quoc island',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    image: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/panorama-of-the-city-of-nha-trang-in-vietnam-from-drone-point-of-view-picture-id827359312?k=20&m=827359312&s=612x612&w=0&h=4QigU_O-sGaDhuFBOS_K66A4cXxc5IUoT4NrbsPw7Oo=',
    title: 'Nha Trang city',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    image: 'https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/298/610/503/vietnam-ho-chi-minh-city-cityscape-dusk-thumbnail.jpg',
    title: 'Ho Chi Minh city',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    image: 'https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/582/203/631/ha-noi-city-vietnam-lake-thumbnail.jpg',
    title: 'Ha Noi city',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    image: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/sunny-beach-in-the-pearl-island-of-phu-quoc-vietnam-picture-id1307905856?b=1&k=20&m=1307905856&s=170667a&w=0&h=MMd7neh6NOOxeUUlo6eCeU49vWp7HhQXtgTw0VNjogo=',
    title: 'Phu Quoc island',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    image: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/panorama-of-the-city-of-nha-trang-in-vietnam-from-drone-point-of-view-picture-id827359312?k=20&m=827359312&s=612x612&w=0&h=4QigU_O-sGaDhuFBOS_K66A4cXxc5IUoT4NrbsPw7Oo=',
    title: 'Nha Trang city',
  },
]
```

Comment: The problem is that all the items that are being rendered in the flatlist shares the selectedId state. When you select another item, the previous id will be overwritten with the new id from the selected item. To fix this, move your state into the renderView function.

Comment: @caslawter sorry I don't understand you yet, could you please explain more detail?

Comment: @Kedo any expo snack for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing  checkedId in your checked component and it rerenders every time one more is checked, it goes to default. You can add isChecked property to your data, it will be false as default. And you just change it to true on press.

This is how you data will look:

```
    const DATA = [
      {
        id: 1,
        image: 'https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/298/610/503/vietnam-ho-chi-minh-city-cityscape-dusk-thumbnail.jpg',
        title: 'Ho Chi Minh city',
        isChecked:false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        image: 'https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/582/203/631/ha-noi-city-vietnam-lake-thumbnail.jpg',
        title: 'Ha Noi city',
        isChecked:false,
      }]
```

You will is element checked based on your data state. And you will have onPress function. You will store you data in use State.

```
const handlePress=(id)=>{
    let arr=data;
    arr.map((item)=>{
    if(item.id===id){
    item.isChecked=!item.isChecked
    }
    //here you will just set you data to arr
    setData(arr)
  })
```

}

Comment: sorry I don't understand you yet, could you please explain more detail?

Comment: I have edited answer: The manin concept  is that you store your data in useState, and with function you change that state.